# Handle Pop-Up While Navigating with IE

Tags: javascript, excel, automation, alert, vba

I have an Excel VBA macro that

1. opens IE,
2. navigates to the Medicare website,
3. logs me in,
4. compares the claims listed on the website with those already in the workbook
5. alerts me to any differences

It is during the log-in step that I have a problem, so I've reproduced that portion of the code below.  As soon as the `.click` line is executed a pop-up window appears asking the user to click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button in order to proceed.  Macro execution is suspended until I manually click the <kbd>OK</kbd>  button on the pop-up.

The source code behind the http://www.mymedicare.gov web page has information relative to the pop-up, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it so that I can programmatically click the pop-up <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

Any help in terms of figuring out how to programmatically click the pop-up's <kbd>OK</kbd> button would be much appreciated.

> note: For the purpose of this question, any user id and password can be used. If you handle the pop-up you'll be passed to a page that says something like incorrect user id / password.
>
> That will indicate that you've been successful in handling the pop-up.

```
Sub Medicare_Claims()' 
' Update the status bar 
  Application.StatusBar = "Running the Medicare Claims subroutine" 

' Open the "MyMedicare web page 
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
    With ie 
        .Visible = True 
        .Navigate "https://www.mymedicare.gov/" 
    End With 

' Loop until the page is fully loaded 
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy 
        DoEvents 
    Loop 
    
' Log-in 
    ie.Document.all.Item("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_HomePage_SWEUserName").Value = "abcde"           
    ie.Document.all.Item("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_HomePage_SWEPassword").Value = "12345"     
    ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_HomePage_SignIn").Click
     
' Loop until the page is fully loaded 
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy 
        DoEvents 
    Loop 

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15")) 

' Navigate further to the Search Claims" web page 
    ie.Navigate "https://www.mymedicare.gov/searchclaims.aspx"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone passes this way again, here is the solution provided by Tim Williams:

```
'Log-in 

ie.Document.all.Item"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_HomePage_SWEUserName").Value= "abcde"

ie.Document.all.Item("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_HomePage_SWEPassword").Value = "12345"

Dim f As String

f = "function(SignIn){document.getElementById'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_HomePage_Agree').value = 'True';}"

ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "window.ConfirmationPopup = " & f, "jscript"

ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_HomePage_SignIn").Click
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}", True` after your login code.

Also, try adding 
`Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Not objIE.Busy` and
 `Do While objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop` any time you need a page to load. In my experience, coupling the two together works pretty well, whereas using just one or the other can sometimes produce errors and using `Application.Wait` can slow down your code unecessarily.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I couldn't get SendKeys to work...ron