# How to input text into textbox of popup window displayed from webpage using excel vba

Tags: javascript, jquery, vba, excel

Using Excel/VBA, I'm trying to input text into a `textbox` that is displayed on a popup window. Here's the code defining the field I need to access:

```
span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"/>
input class="ui-autocomplete-input" id="RUItem" style="width: 100px;" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

I tried using:

```
ie.Document.getElementById("RUItem").Value = "some-value"
```

But I get an error saying:

> Object Required

so I know that I am not accessing it correctly. How do I input text into the secondary window?

Comment: You might need to use windows api?

Comment: check out the accepted answer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773523/handle-pop-up-while-navigating-with-ie). it may be useful.

Comment: I've done this with an autoit application but not VBA.